# Change build tools from VS2010 to VS2015 in command line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, devenv

I want to upgrade a solution in command line, so that I can build that solution / the projects within that solution with VS 2015. But somehow that does not work like expected.

**What I am doing**

1) Download the source code from https://ssl.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/tags/release-56-1/

2) Calling vcvarsall.bat for VS 2015.

3) Changing the `ToolsVersion` for every project

```
for /r "%cd%" %%a in ( *.vcxproj ) do (
    sed.exe -i "s/ToolsVersion=\"4\.0\"/ToolsVersion=\"14\.0\"/g" "%%a"
)
```

4) Upgrade solution

```
rem upgrade solution
devenv "allinone\allinone.sln" /Upgrade
```

But nonetheless, I get warnings like this:

```
warning  : The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (v100) cannot be 
  found. To build using the Visual Studio 2015 (v140) build tools, 
  either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then 
  select "Upgrade Solution...". Install Visual Studio 2010 (v100) to 
  build using the Visual Studio 2010 (v100) build tools.
```

What I am missing? Is there a way how this can be done withing command line / batch ?

Comment: What if you just run `devenv "allinone\allinone.sln" /Upgrade` without manually changing toolsversion? Also what is the output of devenv /upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

You must add this:

```
  <PropertyGroup><PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset><PropertyGroup>
```

Source: used vs2015 to upgrade the projects and checked the diffs

The ToolsVersion you changed refers to msbuild I think. The PlatformToolset is what changes the compiling toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

In the Visual Studio 2015 environment, right click the solution in the Solution Explorer View, and choose "Retarget solution".